# Define a Haskell data structure Cipher to represent a substitution cipher

Tags: haskell, encryption

I am brand new to Haskell and am trying to answer this question? I don't want people to do it for me, but any pointers would be helpful because I don't really have a clue where to begin!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, any of `a -> a`, `[(a, a)]`, or `Map a a` can be an  appropriate representation of a substitution cipher over the alphabet `a`.

Comment: Is a Data Structure the same as a function/definition?

Comment: @Eddie Nope. Hard to say something more helpful unless you ask a better question, though.

Comment: What is a Data Structure in Haskell? Because I know a function or definition consists of a type definition with :: and an equation with = . Or have I misunderstood this as well?

Comment: @Eddie There are plenty of good Haskell tutorials out there. I'm not going to try typing one into a StackOverflow comment.